# Jquery Draggable Not Working On Element Rotated Via CSS Transform And Changing Its Width And Height On First Drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

So i was working on rotating and dragging images for avatar pictures for my website, i estimated that it would take me 3 or 4 hours to add those functionalities to my website, and now it's been 3 days and i haven't been able to do anything with this bug: when an element is rotated (any degree except 0), whenever i try to drag it, the width and height of the dragged element are automatically set to the width and height of the parent, which fucks with the whole `min/max-height` and `min/max-width` process (this happens on 90 and 270 degree rotates, on a 180deg rotate, only the below bug exists).

another bug, whenever i actually drag it, everything is reversed, for example in a 180deg rotate, when i drag my image to the right the element goes to the left, without the 180deg rotate, everything would work fine.

so please someone give me a solution before i commit suicide.

and be careful, on dragging, i want my image to be contained within its parent, so nothing except the image is visible inside the parent (you get this, the html structure i used is because i am working on a profile picture), i added the `#child` because otherwise, whenever i applied the rotates to my image directly, it would go out of its parent and no `transform-origin` combinations would work with all the different image sizes and rotate angles, so i added the `#child`, which is an element with equal height and widths (so the element actually never goes out of its parent when rotating) and i applied my rotates to that element instead of the actual img, and i believe that you get the `#parent`, it is just a container, and if you are asking why i am not using `containment: $("#parent")` in my jquery, it is because that when i added this instead of the whole `drag:function(){}`, the dragging becomes jumpy instead of the smooth dragging effect i get using the current option (run a function on drag).

here's the fiddle and feel free to try different rotation degrees: https://jsfiddle.net/5kkwsLm8/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="parent" style="width:150px;height:150px;overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;background-color:red;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;">
<div id="child"  style="width:100%;height:100%;transform:rotate(180deg)">
<img id="draggable" alt="Hello" src="mario.jpg" alt="mario" style="min-height:100%;max-height:100%;min-width:100%;">
</div>
</div>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var y1 = $("#parent").height();
var x1 = $('#parent').width();
var y2 = $('#draggable').height();
var x2 = $('#draggable').width();



$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
drag: function(event, ui) {
if(ui.position.top >= 0) {
    ui.position.top = 0;
}
else if(ui.position.top <= y1 - y2) {
    ui.position.top = y1 - y2;
} 
if(ui.position.left >= 0) {
    ui.position.left = 0;
}
else if(ui.position.left <= x1 - x2) {
ui.position.left = x1 - x2;
} 
},
stop: function(event, ui) {

}
});

})


</script>
</body>
</html>
```